# How can I access a link with a div id directly in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, pageload

Suppose I have a link, say, `http://www.example.com/index.html#xyz`. When I open it in browser with `www.example.com/index.html` it works fine, but when I have a link targeting `#xyz` on the same page it loads a new `data-role=content` page through ajax.

Now my query is if I access the same URL directly as `http://www.example.com/index.html#xyz`, it loads the `www.example.com/index.html` and not the specific `#xyz` page.

Is there any way to make this work?

NOTE: The `#xyz` page content is loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding `rel="external"` to your link then it will be fine.

**Example:**

Let's suppose that you have 2 HTML files: `index.html` and `page.html`, and that `page.html` contains 2 jQuery Mobile pages: `#p1` and `#p2`.

Now, let's suppose you want to access `#p2` from `index.html` by clicking on a link `<a>`.

You'll need to add `rel="external"` to your link as follows:

```
<a href="page.html#p2" rel="external">GO TO PAGE 2 !</a>
```

---

## Full example:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>    

<body>

<div data-role="page">      
  <div data-role="content">      
    <h1>INDEX.HTML</h1>

    <!-- YOUR LINK TO ACCESS #P2 IN PAGE.HTML -->
    <a href="page.html#p2" rel="external">GO TO PAGE 2 "#P2" !</a>    
  </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`page.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>    

<body>

    <!-- PAGE 1 #P1 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="p1">    
        <div data-role="content">
    <h1>PAGE 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- PAGE 2 #P2 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="p2">
        <div data-role="content">
        <h1>PAGE 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't this works if I dynamically inject data inside the #p1 and #p2 and access the url page.html#p1 through the browser. Anyways thanks for some hints. That's also quite leading me to the way.